# Ubuntu 16.04 and three monitors - doesn't work

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, display, monitor, external-monitor

I connected my Lenovo T460 through the Ultra Docking station with 3 Monitors (LG Flatron E2210) via VGA, HDMI and DP. With Win7 I got them all to run rather quickly (having the laptop-monitor turned off, only the three external ones running), but as you probably can guess, Win7 is only my secondary OS.

My primary is Ubuntu 16.04 and it ran smoothly with 2 external monitors and I was very hopeful about adding the third. But now the monitors work quite fine when it comes to the bootloader, where I choose between Linux and Win7. This shows on all screens. Right after though, they turn off, and only one shows the password screen. After that they usually either turn off completely, not showing anything but black or take turns showing something for a few moments and then they all turn black.

I would REALLY love to have my setup run under Ubuntu, as that's my "productive setup" software-wise.

My tech specs are

- Lenovo T460
- Ultra Docking station
- DVI --> HDMI cable
- DVI --> VGA cable
- DVI --> DP cable
- Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 520
- RAM: 16GB
- CPU: i5-6300 @2.40 GHz

I hope someone could help me here..... thanks so much!

PS: I looked through the forums already but could not find anything that seemed to be helpful to me - keep in mind, I'm kinda new to all this here ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had similar symptoms with totally different hardware setup. Two out of three screens would go black but not always. I changed graphics drivers from default open source to latest proprietary nVidia drivers. Now I have built in laptop monitor plus two external monitors working. It seems like this might be a driver related problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Two monitors worked fine, but it was the third one that threw things off.... I want to use the laptop only as the "processing part" and only the external monitors for "looking at things" ;-)